# ReturnUrl generation after FormsAuthentication.SignOut()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Which part of asp.net mvc is reponsible for the generation of the ReturnUrl. At the moment I am getting this:

```
?ReturnUrl=%2f
```

after:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

This takes place in a model which is invoked like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    _xModel.LogOff();
    return Redirect("/");
}
```

changing this to:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult LogOff()
{
    _xModel.LogOff();
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Which part of asp.net mvc is reponsible for the generation of the ReturnUrl

None. This is not part of ASP.NET MVC at all. It is part of the FormsAuthenticationModule which is automatically registered for each ASP.NET application in which you activate forms authentication. To avoid this happening you should always redirect after signing out a user:

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Comment: thanks. should have said asp.net rather than asp.net mvc - sorry. see edited question though ...

Comment: I don't understand what you mean when you are saying `it does not work` after changing your code to use `RedirectToAction("Index", "Home")`. What is the expected and what is the actual outcome? Also is the Index action on Home controller a protected resource?

Comment: I expect ReturnUrl to contain the uri where the user is before (s)he logs out rather than %2f.

Comment: No, you cannot expect such thing. The ReturnUrl property is set by the forms authentication module only when an anonymous user attempts to hit a protected resource, so that when he logs in he is redirected back to the resource he was trying to access.

Comment: oh I see - sorry I muddled this up.

Comment: actually the reason why I got confused is that the logoff method (see question) produces ?ReturnUrl=%2f. why is this and how can I prevent this? Thanks.